# Creating a website from a set of graphical design images

Tags: html, css

I've been working on a website for a while. The functionality of the site works nicely, but the graphical design looks a bit crap, so we paid a graphic designer to have a look at it for us. He  has sent us a set of images - one for each page on the site - with a suggested new design. It looks pretty good, but I don't know what to do with these images...

Do I just start messing around with the css - setting colors, sizes, etc, to make it look like the designs I have been given? Or is there a procedure I should follow? Should I badger the guy for more information about fonts, color shades, etc?

Comment: The information should be available to you if the project has been completed. Either in the PSD files (if the designer used Photoshop) or on a list somewhere.

Comment: You should ask for a "source file". For example, a Photoshop `.psd`. You have Photoshop, right? Failing that, you can ask which fonts were used. You can find out which colours have been used by using an "eyedropper tool".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, you need a HTML designer to create HTML/CSS for the graphic designs, so asking the designer for it might be an option. He should be able to at least provide a style guide detailing colors, fonts etc.

If you have to do it yourself, there are a couple of tools to help you:

- [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/): The ultimate web developer helper tool
- [Pixel Perfect](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/pixel-perfect/): An add-on to Firebug, that lets you overlay an image onto the site you are developing.
- [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage): Really nice and easy testing tool for the different IE versions.
- A screen ruler: A simple tool to measure distances in images and in your site.

Answer (score 2):

The usual procedure if you have a complete website design made in photoshop or any other image editing program is that you slice the image ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slicing_(interface_design)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slicing_%28interface_design%29)) and then put it together again by aligning the sliced pictures with html.

Of course you could also recreate the design with css and html elements but depending on the complexity of the received design this will be quite hard or even nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You have different tools that will help you to choose a color and font 
automatically.  You can ask him to send you photoshop files with all fonts and color that
he did

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to break up the design into components like buttons, menus, boxes, header, footer and so on. Then you can create the HTML/CSS code according to the design and assemble all the compnents. I suggest you to ask your designer to pass you color values and measurements so you can concentrate on the code instead of finding those information.

Answer (score 1):

As @Matschie and @Gregory have commented, you are best to request the raw design files from them so that these can be cut up for use with your HTML/CSS.

Flat images, such as JPEGs, should only be for previewing the design, and should not be built from.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do the CSS yourself or you can go to one of the many sites out there that will do it for you. There are a ton of sites that will turn images (usually photoshop PSD files) into working CSS/HTML. A lot of these sites are pretty cheap and seeing as how you paid a graphic designer to put together a nice looking design, I would suggest going to one of these sites and paying them for good CSS/HTML. Good CSS/HTML can get a bit complicated with cross browser issues and stuff like that and unless you have a lot of experience with it, it can take a lot of time.

Some examples of sites that provide such services are:

[psd2html](http://www.psd2html.com/)

[xhtmlchop](http://www.xhtmlchop.com/)

[xhtmljunction](http://www.xhtmljunction.com/)

If you just do a google search on PSD to HTML you'll find a whole lot more.